# Dataset constraints when using LDA

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, pattern-recognition, discriminant-analysis

Given a dataset for dimension reduction using linear discriminant analysis (LDA), I was told that the number of dimensions should not exceed the number of samples. Why is it the case?

Thank you